# What is a MultiPolygonZM geometry type?

Tags: postgis

My imported shapefiles (shp2pgsl) have the geometry type "MultiPolygonZM".

```
geom geometry(MultiPolygonZM),
```

What is this type of multi polygon? I can't find any useful information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type is a "4D" geometry type, so the geometry record contains X,Y, Z and M data.

Where **X,Y,Z** are 3D coordinates and **M** stands for measurement.

Take a look at this discussion: [Is the Fourth Dimension used in GIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5851/is-the-fourth-dimension-used-in-gis)