# Spatio-Temporal Plot on a Basemap

Tags: postgis, leaflet, visualisation, spatio-temporal-data

I have trajectory data in LineStringM format and visualize relevant results via Leaflet on street map tiles. I was wondering whether it is possible to visualize spatiotemporal plots on OSM tiles.

I understand that there are commercial software solutions providing what I am interested in but I was wondering whether it is possible to achieve similar results in a simple manner without drastically changing my workflow using open-source alternatives. It looks like a similar question has been asked [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408/visualisation-of-spatio-temporal-data-set) before though the answers might be outdated.

Comment: You could simply visualize in a similar way using MapBox GL JS V1 and set a z value for each hour, since you are using 3 dimensional data (with time instead of height) that might work. You could also try using the R plotly to combine its [3D and map plots](https://plotly.com/r/3d-charts/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not be exactly what you are looking for, but you could use QGIS for something similar, for example, I created a points layer with a date-time field which was filled with `now()` as the default value when I added each point.
I then set a `z` field and populated it with this expression (`test` being my layer):

```
(epoch( "time" ) - epoch(attribute( get_feature_by_id('test',1),'time')))/1000
```

This gave me a table looking something like the first picture, where every second adds another meter of elevation (or another `z` anyway)

[image]

I then used the `Set Z Value` processing tool and with a z value set I could visualize my layer in a 3D map view.

I would recommend maybe adding an additional ~50 meters to set a base height above the terrain, but that's up to you.

[image]

You could probably get something similar with a maplibre js map but if want a relatively simpler solution, this might work.